# VS 2022 can't build .NET Framework 4.5 but dotnet CLI can build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I used CLI to check and my PC have installed .net4.5 like below

```
PS C:\Users\Wei> dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework"


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        11/13/2021  12:45 AM                v4.0
d-----        11/13/2021  12:45 AM                v4.5
d-----        12/29/2021  12:58 AM                v4.5.1
d-----        11/13/2021  12:45 AM                v4.5.2
d-----        11/13/2021  12:45 AM                v4.6
d-----        11/13/2021  12:45 AM                v4.6.1
d-----        11/13/2021  12:46 AM                v4.7.2
d-----        11/13/2021  12:51 AM                v4.8
d-----        11/13/2021  12:45 AM                v4.X
```

And I used `dotnet build` project and it's work successfully like image

[image]

But if I build by visual studio 2022 on this PC, it can't build successfully, and show error message like below, and I tried to install again v4.5 but it's also not work.

```
Error   MSB3644 The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
```

[image]

[image]

But I tried on another PC VS 2022 17.0.0 and it's work successfully

[image]

Comment: Have you checked what it says? Go to the Visual Studio Installer and check you have ".NET Targeting Pack for .NET Framework" (or similar) installed. If possible, I would recommend to upgrade to 4.8. Anything earlier is seriously out of date.

Comment: @PMF Yes, but we need v4.5 for old projects, and example another vs 2022 is work successfully

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 does not officially support .NET Framework 4.5. Only 4.6.2+. See the "Visual Studio 2022 Support for .NET Development" section here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/compatibility#-visual-studio-2022-support-for-net-development

Comment: @vcsjones thanks, but when I installed vs 2019 then vs 2022 can support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get Visual Studio 2022 to build .Net Framework 4.5 I had to first install visual studio 2019. Then Visual Studio 2022 was able to build net4.5.

And if I follow the Error message to `https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks` to download and install net4.5 SDK, it was not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to target older versions of Net Framework in VS 2022 is downloading the reference assemblies from nuget.org open as zip and copy the content of build\.NETFramework\ to Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework